# "Error: 'train.default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:caret'" when trying to run caret::train()

Tags: r, namespaces, r-caret

Every time I try to train a model using caret::train() e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

#reprex df x vals:
mydata <- data.frame(product = sample(c("apples", "pears", "carrots", "potatoes"), replace=TRUE),
                     temperature_C = rnorm(1000, mean=15, sd=10),
                     weekday = sample(c("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"), replace=TRUE),
                     weight = rnorm(1000, mean=300, sd=50))

#reprex df y vals:
mydata$value = mydata$weight + 10*mydata$temperature_C + rnorm(1000,70,25) + 
  case_when(mydata$weekday %in% c("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday") ~ 200,
            mydata$weekday %in% c("thursday", "friday") ~ -150,
            TRUE ~ NA_real_)

#create folds
myFolds <- createFolds(mydata$value, k = 10)


# Create traincontrol object
myControl_continuous  = trainControl(verboseIter = TRUE, index = myFolds )

 # Fit a glmnet:
 model_glmnet <- caret::train(
       value ~ .,
       mydata,
       metric = "RMSE",
       method = "glmnet",
       tuneLength = 100,
       trControl = myControl_continuous,
       preProcess = c("zv", "knnImpute", "center", "scale")
     )
```

I receive the error message:

> Error: 'train.default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:caret'

I did reinstall caret alongside all of my other libraries yesterday, so it (and all other packages) should definitely be the latest version. It was also running fine this morning after the reinstallation, which is what I find particularly odd.

Please can anyone advise how to resolve this?

Comment: Reinstall `caret` package and rerun the code. In my system, your code is working fine.

Comment: works for me too